# Implementing Exclusive Face Biometric Authentication in Kotlin Android App

Tags: android, kotlin, security, face-recognition, user-experience

Greetings fellow developers,

I'm currently in the process of building an Android app using Kotlin, and I've hit a roadblock while trying to implement a **face biometric authentication feature**. My intention is to have a **solely face-based biometric authentication**, **excluding any other methods like fingerprint, PIN, or password** etc. Despite my efforts, I've been unable to achieve my precise goal using the`androidx.biometric:biometric-ktx:1.2.0-alpha05` library.

I've delved into the Android BiometricPrompt API through this library, but most resources and examples I've encountered demonstrate multi-biometric approaches, combining fingerprint and face recognition. My focus is on creating an **exclusive face biometric authentication experience, leveraging the power of modern facial recognition technology.**

Have any of you had success with such an implementation using the `androidx.biometric` library or **any other relevant libraries?** I come to you in the hope of receiving guidance, whether it's a workaround using the current library or an alternative solution that aligns with my requirements.

Thank you immensely for your time and assistance!

Comment: "My intention is to have a solely face-based biometric authentication, excluding any other methods like fingerprint, PIN, or password etc." -- that is not supported by Android natively, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, then biometric authentication involving multiple biometric methods like fingerprint and face, it is possible. right?

Comment: With Android, [you can specify whether you want strong biometrics, weak biometrics, device credentials (such as a PIN), or some combination of those](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth?hl=en#declare-supported-authentication-types). Android decides how to map particular types of biometrics (face, fingerprint, etc.) into those categories.

Comment: I'm also curious on this. Is it your intention to have face biometrics as the sole sign-up and log-in method? Or sign-up by some other means, and face biometrics as the log-in only?